# Which data type I need to use to store value between 0 to 1 upto 2 decimal points in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add column in table called `value` which needs to store value from 0 to 1 up to 2 decimal points i.e. 0.25 0.50 0.75 0.80 etc..

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `decimal(3,2)` will give you -9.99 to 9.99. Add a check constraint if you want just 0.00 to 1.00.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your specified range includes both bounds, use [decimal(3,2) or numeric(3,2)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL). Add a [CHECK constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) to reject negative numbers. [Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mxk_jthA).

```sql
create table test (
  yournum numeric(3,2),
  check (yournum between 0 and 1));
```

Test (note the rounding behaviour):

```sql
insert into test values
  (-0.0049),
  (-0.001),
  (0),
  (0.001),
  (0.2),
  (0.201),
  (0.234),
  (0.2345),
  (0.2349),
  (0.235),
  (0.239),
  (1),
  (1.001),
  (1.0049)
returning *;
-- yournum
-----------
--    0.00
--    0.00
--    0.00
--    0.00
--    0.20
--    0.20
--    0.23
--    0.23
--    0.23
--    0.24
--    0.24
--    1.00
--    1.00
--    1.00
--(14 rows)
--INSERT 0 14
```

Example rejects:

```sql
insert into test values (-0.005) returning *;
--ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_yournum_check"
--DETAIL:  Failing row contains (-0.01).
insert into test values (1.005) returning *;
--ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_yournum_check"
--DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1.01).
insert into test values (11) returning *;
--ERROR:  numeric field overflow
--DETAIL:  A field with precision 3, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1.
insert into test values ('Infinity'::float) returning *;
--ERROR:  numeric field overflow
--DETAIL:  A field with precision 3, scale 2 cannot hold an infinite value.
insert into test values ('NaN'::float) returning *;
--ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_yournum_check"
--DETAIL:  Failing row contains (NaN).
```

Comment: 1.00 will not be allowed. You need `decimal(3,2)`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Your `CHECK` allows values from 0 to 1: `select  1 between 0 and 1; t`, but the type specification(`decimal(2,2)`) does not.

Comment: @jarlh I edited my answer to use the new range assumption. Strictly speaking "store value from 0 to 1" can indicate a (0,1), (0,1] as well as [0,1] range, but I have to agree the last one is most likely the requirement. My mind was with partitioning ranges, where the default is lower bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I could only tag/notify one person at a time but my response above applies to your comment as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `smallint` and, store the value multiplied by 100 and add a check constraint that makes sure that the value is between 0 and 100.
This minimizes storage space and makes calculations faster.

The down side is of course that some of your calculations have to be changed. Addition is pretty straightforward, but you'd have to divide by 100 after multiplying two numbers.

Comment: In this case [the size is the same but calculations do run faster](https://dbfiddle.uk/IQiMTTSv). Weighing what smallest data type the input can be mapped to, versus the overhead necessary to then handle it, versus the ease of use - is a good practice in general. My guess is while I'm upvoting this as a valuable answer, the other vote actually downvotes not it, but the downsides outlined in it.

Comment: @Zegarek I agree. It depends a lot on what you do with the data, which OP doesn't disclose. But the `numeric` will use more than two bytes.